# Generic regular expression

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

Ok, let's start again, more details now.

I fetch my_meta['lieux']. At this moment, it looks like to

```
string(176) "Paris:10/06/2013->link:20/09/2013->link
Londres:04/06/2014->link:23/09/2014->link
Toulouse:05/12/2015->link:05/12/2015->link"
```

After this first step, I make a split to store in different key/value each lines

```
$str = $my_meta['lieux'];
$arr = split("\n", $str);
```

it return this array

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>string(82) "Paris:10/06/2013->link:20/09/2013->link"
  [1]=>string(46) "Londres:04/06/2014->link:23/09/2014->link"
  [2]=>string(46) "Toulouse:05/12/2015->link:05/12/2015->link"
}
```

Now what I want it to store in differents key/value the country and for each countries the dates/links associated.

At the moment I make something like that

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
  preg_match("/^(\w+)\:(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)->(\w+)\:(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)->(\w+)/", $arr[$i], $lieux_[$i]);
}
```

When I print the lieux_[$i] I have

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>string(43) "Paris:10/06/2013->link:20/09/2013->link"
  [1]=>string(5) "Paris"
  [2]=>string(10) "10/06/2013"
  [3]=>string(6) "link"
  [4]=>string(10) "20/09/2013"
  [5]=>string(6) "link"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>string(45) "Londres:04/06/2014->link:23/09/2014->link"
  [1]=>string(7) "Londres"
  [2]=>string(10) "04/06/2014"
  [3]=>string(6) "link"
  [4]=>string(10) "23/09/2014"
  [5]=>string(6) "link"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>string(46) "Toulouse:05/12/2015->link:05/12/2015->link"
  [1]=>string(8) "Toulouse"
  [2]=>string(10) "05/12/2015"
  [3]=>string(6) "link"
  [4]=>string(10) "05/12/2015"
  [5]=>string(6) "link"
}
```

So it's pretty nice, I can after this, create a loop to insert my data in the good div etc...

**But here is the problem**, if I add more date/link (`:04/06/2014->link`) it's not working anymore because the regex is wrong (If I have two dates/link for each country it's working, otherwise, it's not working anymore).

I would like to get something like that :

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>string(43) "Paris:10/06/2013->link:20/09/2013->link:20/09/2013->link:20/09/2013->link"
  [1]=>string(5) "Paris"
  [2]=>string(10) "10/06/2013"
  [3]=>string(6) "link"
  [4]=>string(10) "20/09/2013"
  [5]=>string(6) "link"
  [6]=>string(10) "20/09/2013"
  [7]=>string(6) "link"
  [8]=>string(10) "20/09/2013"
  [9]=>string(6) "link"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>string(45) "Londres:04/06/2014->link"
  [1]=>string(7) "Londres"
  [2]=>string(10) "04/06/2014"
  [3]=>string(6) "link"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>string(46) "Toulouse"
  [1]=>string(8) "Toulouse"
}
array(10) {
  [0]=>string(43) "country4:10/06/2013->link:20/09/2013->link:20/09/2013->link:20/09/2013->link"
  [1]=>string(5) "country4"
  [2]=>string(10) "10/06/2013"
  [3]=>string(6) "link"
  [4]=>string(10) "20/09/2013"
  [5]=>string(6) "link"
  [6]=>string(10) "20/09/2013"
  [7]=>string(6) "link"
  [8]=>string(10) "20/09/2013"
  [9]=>string(6) "link"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to verify the format, or *capture* an unkown amount of dates/links?

Comment: Yes, I would to capture to the differents dates/links.

Comment: Then you'll need to look at each line individually and utilize `preg_match_all` instead.

Comment: But at the moment I can already capture in differents array the values, but only if there is 2 dates/links, because I made a `for loop` to inspect each lines.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because your regexp explicitly has exactly two dates and two links.

For a 1+ dates and links, use the below.

```
/^(\w+)(\:(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)->(\w+))+/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/okT0xpPyi1a-MPqX)

Comment: There is probably a mistake in the regex http://goo.gl/htLorn

Comment: Ooh and sorry, it's for digits for the year.

Comment: @Jeremdsgn: Yes, it was because the year format in the question was changed sometime back.

Comment: But even with this solution it doesn't work. Do you see the link I posted on comment, there are the four digits and there is a problem.
**edit :** I want the country, the date, and the link in different cases.

Comment: This can't work because when you repeat a capturing group with a quantifier, the result is always the last value (in other words, all the precedent values have been replaced by the last)

Comment: I made an update on my initial post.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this pattern:

```
preg_match_all(
    '~(?:^(?<country>\w+)|\G):(?<date>(?:[0-9]{2}/){2}[0-9]{4})->(?<link>\w+)~',
    $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($matches as $match) {
    echo '<br/>' . $match['date'] . "\t" . $match['link'];
}
```

EDIT: assuming that your text is now an array of lines (`$lines`), you can do this:

```
$lines = split("\n", $str);
$results = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    preg_match_all(
        '~(?:^(?<country>\w+)|\G):(?<date>(?:[0-9]{2}/){2}[0-9]{4})->(?<link>\w+)~',
        $line, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach($matches as $match) {
        if ($match['country']) $country = $match['country'];
        $results[$country][] = array(
                           'date' => $match['date'],
                           'link' => $match['link']);
    }
}
print_r($results);
```

Comment: It returns this type of array  `Array
(
    [0] => Paris:10/06/2013->BLIO20
    [date] => 10/06/2013
    [1] => 10/06/2013
    [link] => BLIO20
    [2] => BLIO20
)` I want have the date and after the link, not all the dates to the beginning and the links to the end.

Comment: @Jeremdsgn: In this case, You must add the PREG_SET_ORDER option. See my edit.

Comment: Ok, it's not working neither. And I must use preg_match, because I already made some operations before in a loop. :(

Comment: @Jeremdsgn: You can't use preg_match for this kind of task, it's impossible since you have an undetermined number of date/link occurences by line. Use the code I give you to compose the array you want, it's easy. (you could for example remove all numeric keys from `$matches`)

Comment: @Jeremdsgn: Ok, you don't seems to make it easily, i will give you the complete code.

Comment: I updated my initial post, because I don't understand anything now. When I use your regex, there is a double array for the same line.

Comment: The countries don't appear anymore ? I need to keep them to save the parent status of the dates/links. thanks in advance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41328/discussion-between-jeremdsgn-and-casimir-et-hippolyte)

Comment: @Jeremdsgn: No, try this last edit.

Comment: Sorry the link was a misclick. For each dates/links it duplicate the country. It is possible to have only one array for each country (and have the dates/links below) like the result I get on the initial post ? edit : I'm sorry because, I thought I was near to the "answer" with the first regex, but I need to change all the things to work again.